# how to close view decorated whit MvxSidebarPresentation attribute?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

In my iOS application there is a button in home view. When I click that button it shows this view:

```
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, true)]
public partial class ProductsView : BaseViewController<ProductsViewModel>
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
       var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ProductsView, ProductsViewModel>();
                  
       set.Bind(BtnClose).To(vm => vm.CloseViewCommand);
               
       set.Apply();
    }  
}
```

but when I click BtnClose I get these warnings

> mvx: Warning: 100.30 Hint ignored MvxClosePresentationHint
>
> mvx: Warning: 100.30 Could not close ViewModel type ProductsViewModel

I need to close this view anyway.

Comment: How are you closing it from `ProductsViewModel` in your `CloseViewCommand`?

Comment: public MvxCommand CloseViewCommand
        { get { return new MvxCommand(() => Close(this)); } }

Answer (score 0):

What ever the view you are saying if that view is integration with main view. Just try with Btn.ResignFirstResponder();

Comment: what do you main with "view is integration with main view" ??
i tried  "this.ResignFirstResponder();"  but dosn't work !!

Comment: I say it shouldn't be a sub view.

Comment: you mean that it must be root view ?!